# Why i get 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'days_count' this error in my code

Tags: python, django, nonetype, traceback

I want to multiple days_count * room_service but after multiple i see this outpout which is not suitable . Please See the image where Room_Cost is like 800days, 000 whats the solution please help me..

```
class PatientDischarge(models.Model):
assign_doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
appointment = models.ForeignKey(Appointment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
release_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, null=True)
medicine_cost = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
other_charge = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.appointment.patient.name if all([self.appointment, self.appointment.patient, self.appointment.patient.name]) else 0

def days_count(self):
    return self.release_date - self.appointment.entry_date if all([self.appointment, self.appointment.entry_date]) else 0

def room_bill(self):
    return self.days_count() * self.appointment.room_service if all([self.appointment, self.appointment.room_service])  else 0
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please paste complete error log?

Comment: The error means that `PatientDischarge` object is None and you cannot call `PatientDischarge` method `days_count()` on a NoneType object. You can see from the traceback where this is failing. Probably somewhere in views.

Answer (score 1):

when you subtract one day from another, you get timedelta, but you need days. modify you days count

```
def days_count(self):
    return (self.release_date - self.appointment.entry_date).days if all([self.appointment, self.appointment.entry_date]) else 0
```